# Common Lisp: Why not the array literal evaluate arguments?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Why is it that the Common Lisp array syntax is not evaluating its arguments:

```
(let ((a 1)) #2A((a 2) (3 4)))
=> #2A((A 2) (3 4))
```

I would have guessed it was `#2A((1 2) (3 4))`.  Is this because `A` is not available at reader time?

Comment: Would you expect the list literal `'((a 3) (3 4))` to evaluate?

Comment: Is `'((a 2) (3 4))` a list literal?  I thought it was the `quote` and `((a 2) (3 4))` was list literal.

Comment: The `'` is just a reader macro for `quote`. So '`((a 2) (3 4))` is just `(quote ((a 2) (3 4)))`. In the source code for a common lisp program, the quoted list is a list literal. Bare lists represent the code of the program, not its data. It's a little confusing at first, but it'll make sense later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, yes.

`#2A((A 2) (3 4))` is not an abbreviation ("syntactic sugar") for `(make-array '(2 2) :initial-contents (list (list a 2) (list 3 4)))`.  If anything, it could be rationalized as `(make-array '(2 2) :initial-contents (quote ((A 2) (3 4))))`, but this would be a bit misleading as the array construction already happens at read-time.